# Is there software that will do reverse geocoding to convert photographs' GPS locations to addresses?

Tags: software, geotagging, reverse-geocoding

I am using a standalone GPS tracker that produces GPX files and then clock-sync photos with it using Microsoft Pro Photo Tools. This works pretty well. But I was also using a feature of Pro Photo Tools called "Get location text" which uses the latitude/longitude information from EXIF and translates it using Windows Live services to actuall addresses. At least it used to, but stopped recently, probalby because of some change of the online API or whatever, and a lack of update for the software.

So, the questions is: do you know of any other software that can bulk translate location info into addresses and write that back into the photo's metadata?

Comment: Are you interested in any particular locale?

Comment: I expect the solution to use Google Maps or Bing Maps APIs - both provide (reverse) geocoding world-wide, and work quite well through  their websites. I find it hard to believe that no one has created an app yet that would do this in bulk for photos.

Comment: try posting this in the GIS Stackexhange:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21213/is-there-software-that-will-do-reverse-geocoding-to-convert-photographs-gps-loc

Answer (score 5):

Jeffrey Friedl's [Geooencoding plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/gps) for [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/) can do this.   It achieves it by querying Google Maps.

There is a also a public beta test for Lightroom 4 (the full release of Lightroom 4 will presumably happen later this year), and it has some more abilities in the mapping area.   I don't know how much it overlaps with Jeffrey's plugin.  But it doesn't matter really, since Jeffrey's plugin is donationware anyway - you pay as much as you like for it.

Comment: I downloaded Lightroom 4 Beta and Jeffrey's plugin and they do work pretty well, but it would be an overkill to buy Lightroom just for this feature... Still hoping to find a simple tool just for the job.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using Windows:
Try http://www.geosetter.de/en/ 
It has a nice list of features and the best UI of all gecoding tools I've come across.

Answer (score -3):

This is a website that I created for the same purpose:

[PicGPS.com](http://PicGPS.com) is a powerful tool that can get a street address out of any picture taken with a mobile device (“Location services” and “Geo Tagging” has to be turned on).

Comment: Given the whois info for the site you've linked lists a "Yovav Gad" as the owner of that domain, could you please edit this answer to clarify your relationship with the site?

Comment: Yes, it's my little web site, what's your point?

Comment: The [help center](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) is **very** clear on this: "However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers." (emphasis original) You have not done so; why not?

Comment: I bet nobody really read those guidelines, but thanks to you, this critical issue was corrected.